# pushing selected date from daterangepicker into url

Tags: javascript, php

I want the date selected from daterangepicker to be appended as a parameter in url.
I have added the code I have so far below.
In my php I want to be able to $_GET['start'] and $_GET['end']. Please tell me how I can do this. :) thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />



    <input type="hidden" id="from" name="from" />


    <input type="hidden" id="to" name="to" />


<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 15%; margin: 0px auto ;Float: right;>
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {

                      $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
       $('#to').val(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
       $('#from').val(end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));



   }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({


        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

 cb(start, end);
});

</script>
```

Comment: looks like your hidden inputs have the names "from" and "to", they will appear as `$_GET['from']`  and `$_GET['to']` I would suggest renaming those inputs or using their names as it stands now, you also need to wrap them with a form

Comment: are you using ajax call to get data from php file?

Answer (score 0):

you can append the date to the url then refresh the page if you are calling the same page

```
var url = window.location.href;    
if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
   url += '&todate='+ todate +'&fromdate='+fromdate;
}else{
url += '&todate='+ todate +'&fromdate='+fromdate;
}
window.location.href = url;
```